# Is System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferManager thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, buffer-manager

I create a buffer manager through static member of `BufferManager.CreateBufferManager`. This new created `BufferManager` is used by multiple threads.

Should I use a `lock` with `TakeBuffer()` and `ReturnBuffer()` or it is thread-safe by design ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally `BufferManager.CreateBufferManager` returns an instance of `WrappingBufferManager` which employs no form of concurrency control, but wraps multiple instances of `SynchronizedPool<T>` which employ internal locking when `Take()`ing a new buffer. So judging by the simplicity of the `WrappingBufferManager`, it's safe to assume that any locking on your part would be redundant, and the returned class is in actual fact thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced thread issues with BufferManager. I created a custom message encoder in WCF, and based on my observation, it's not always guaranteed that buffer manager gets created for each call. Therefore, bytes are being reused/returned by other threads, thus corrupting my data.

So, to answer your question... No they are **NOT**. Since you are reusing the same instance, they are not guaranteed [thread-safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX).